# How to set title in ejs template?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I tried setting title using

```
app.set('title', 'My Site');
```

And in the ejs temlplate, I tried using it.

```
<h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html"><%= title %><span>.</span></a></h1>
```

But, getting below error.

```
title is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:12:26)
    at header (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at include (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:690:39)
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:18:17)
    at portfolio (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\crypto_assets\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
```

Comment: You need to pass an object with the `title` property to the function that you call to render the EJS template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.set()` is used to define a setting against the name with its value e.g. `app.set('foo', 'bar') set the` foo`value to`bar`. To access the setting value, you need to use` app.get()`method as`app.get('foo')`. You can't just access it via name in` app.js` (or any other) file and in templates.

As mentioned in comment, you need to pass object as title property from where you're rendering the the view.

```js
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Express" });
});
```

In case, if you're looking for a variable that you can use throughout all the templates, can define it using `res.locals` property in middleware such as,

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.title = "Marker";

  next();
});
```

With this, you can now use the `title` in view.